# How do I add a ComboBox to a DataGridViewRow in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview

I am using the code

```
DataGridViewRow dViewRow = new DataGridViewRow();    
DataGridViewTextBoxCell Sno = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();    
DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgCombo = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

dViewRow.Cells.Add(Sno);
dViewRow.Cells.Add(dgCombo);
dViewRow.Cells[0].Value = 1;
dViewRow.Cells[1].Value = "ASP";
```

Then I bind `DataGridViewRow` to the main `DataGrid` using `gridViewProducts.Rows.Add(dViewRow);`

But I receive the following error:

System.ArgumentException:DatagridviewCombobox value is not valid

Comment: Do you have any DataSource attached to the `ComboBoxColumn` what the error implies is that the value(ASP) is not available/valid for the combobox. so please add details for the same to the post

Answer (score -1):

User TemplateField

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="List">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="dlBox" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: DropDownList not support in c# windows application